# Outlet/Action problems in Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, xcode, viewcontroller

I've searched for a few hours to try and figure out the answer, but haven't as of yet. 
On creating an outlet/action for an iOS app in Xcode 5:

I'm trying to create an outlet (by CTRL-dragging) from a label in Main.storyboard to ViewController.h (which I had to manually select in the Assistant Editor because only UIViewController.h shows up under "automatic")

No "outlet/connection/action" menu shows up when I drag. However, a menu does show up if I try to drag to the UIViewController.h file. (It just then tells me UIViewController.h is locked, and I can't unlock it)

I've also tried putting "ViewController.h" into the custom class part, as that seemed to work for some other askers out there.

I believe it may (?) have something to do with ViewController.h not showing up under "Automatic" in Assistant Editor. I have tried creating an outlet with a different project and that seems to work, and ViewController.h shows up under automatic.

I'd like to have posted a screenshot but I need 10 reputation. Anyway, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Custom Class` in the storyboard to a class that you have written that subclasses `UIViewController`.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response!

Comment: To my understanding you can only set the `Custom Class` to a class that subclasses what the object is. So trying to put `UIViewController` as the `Custom Class` of a `Label` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the scene you are using is under the `UIViewController` class that you intend on using it with.

**Here is how:**

1. Select Scene (click black bar underneath || **ctrl+shft+click** || Document Oultine)
2. Select Identity Inspector
3. Enter `UIViewController` class of interest under **Custom Class**